# In Google Script, how do I embed a script into a button?

Tags: javascript, button, click, google-apps-script

The reason I am specifying Google Script and not just javascript in general is because the examples I have found for javascript all use html, which Google Script does not appear to play well with outside of basic formatting commands.

I have one function formSubmitReply() which sends an email based on a form submission, and another addToCalendar() that automatically populates the form submission into a Calendar event. Both of these have been tested independently and function well.

What I am attempting to do is to include an "Add to Calendar" button in the email that will execute addToCalendar() when clicked.

The difficulty I keep encountering is the error "TypeError: Cannot find function addToCalendar in object Generic." How do I get around this?

Here are the relevant pieces of my code:

```
// Button setup
function doGet() 
{

  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  // Create button and give it a click handler
  var button = app.createButton("Add to Calendar").setId("button");
  button.addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler("formSubmitReply"));
  app.add(button);

  return app;

}

// Email function
function formSubmitReply(e) 
{

  // Call "button" application
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  /* Additional function code; excluded here */

  // Send email
  GmailApp.sendEmail(userEmail,
                    "Event Support Request Submitted",
                     message + 
                     app.getElementById("button").addToCalendar(e),
                    {name:"Media Services"});

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is posible to call an apps script function like that from an email button(or any js though i might be mistaken on that one). What you could do is serialize the information from e.Then embed a url to a apps script that will handle the encoded information passed as parameters. Url lengths are limited so you might want to embed a form that submits the data to a apps script if the data you are sending is very large.